# Converting from vhdl to verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

This is the following VHDL statement from Testbench;

```
size_data <= to_unsigned(16,16); // data stream is 16 bits in size
```

How to convert that into verilog?

Answer (score 0):

Verilog does type conversion automatically.

This is a signed value:
`wire signed [4:0] I_am_signed;
assign I_am_signed = 16;`

This is unsigned:
`wire [4:0] I_am_unsigned;
assign I_am_unsigned = 16;`

This goes wrong:
`wire signed [3:0] I_am_signed_but_too_small_for_16;
assign I_am_signed_but_too_small_for_16= 16;`

In the last case you are not guaranteed to get warnings or errors but most compilers will provide one. However that will not be the case where it does not know the values. This can go horrible wrong:
`assign I_am_signed_but_too_small_for_16 = I_am_signed;`

But this is a safe way to convert from signed to unsigned or vice versa:
`assign I_am_unsigned = I_am_signed;
 assign I_am_signed   = I_am_unsigned;`